# Google Maps Autocomplete not providing full address for search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using Google Maps API with autocomplete.

The autocomplete is working but many addresses of businesses do NOT have a number attached to them and this is causing problems with searching.

Example:

Google Autocomplete option: Alley Katz, O Street, Sacramento, CA, United States

Should be: Alley Katz, 2019 O St, Sacramento, CA, United States

But instead it fills with Alley Katz, O Street, Sacramento, CA, United States and the search marker is placed on O street no where near the correct address of 2019 O St.

Why does autocomplete remove the number from the address? I know of the formatted_address parameter but how can I access the autocomplete option object after a search is performed and then pass it in to get the correct destination? Or is there a way to display autocomplete options with the full address?

```html
 <html>
          <head>
            <title>Simple Map</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>
              html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
              }
              #map {
                height: 100%;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" /> <a href="#" onclick="searchAddress();">Search</a>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script>
              var map;
              function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                  zoom: 8
                });
                var options = {
                    componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
                };
                var input = document.getElementById('address');
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
                
                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            
            var testvar = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
            var customLat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
            var customLng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
            
            console.log('testvar: ' + testvar);
            console.log(customLat);
            console.log(customLng);
        
        });
              
                
                
              }
              
              function searchAddress() {
                var address =        document.getElementById('address').value;
                console.log('start address: ' + address);
                
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        search_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        search_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                        console.log('end address coordinates: ' + search_lat + ', ' + search_lng);

                        for (var i=0; i<endMarkers.length;i++) {
                            if (i > 0) {
                                testy = i - 1;
                                endMarkers[testy].setMap(null);
                            }
                        }
                        
                            map.setCenter(end_address_marker.getPosition());

                           
                        map.setZoom(15);
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                    } else {

                        

                    }

                });
                
              }
              
              
            </script>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap&libraries=places"
            async defer></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: what are you typing in the search box?

Comment: the name of a business.. so it doesn't start with a number. but if you select a business from the autocomplete options like "Alley Katz, O Street, Sacramento, CA, United States " then it just searches without a number attached to O street, resulting in incorrect marker placement and destination address

Comment: I tried searching for alley katz in google maps and same result as yours, so it is nothing to do with API, it is the way google has associated that business name to the address.

Comment: No, the autocomplete option object has a "formatted_address" value that contains the number associated with the address. That same Alley Katz address has what Im talking about. I'm just confused about passing the formatted_address in before searching?

Comment: Do you mean to say "number associated to business name" ??

Comment: See my updated fiddle. I logged the formatted_address value. Search Alley Katz again and you'll see the 2019 included in the formatted_address value (check console)